# Is is possible to set a large set of constraints for the Solver in Excel using named ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, solver

So, I have a 50 variables that have a minimumum and a maximum bound.

I want to set these as constraints.

The 50 variables are in cells A1 through A50

The maximum constraints are in B1 through B50 and the mininums are in C1 through C50.

Can I name A1:A50 A, B1:B50 B, and C1:C50 C and then set the constraint as follows:

```
SolverAdd cellRef:="A", relation:=1, formulaText:="B"
```

and

```
SolverAdd cellRef:="A", relation:=3, formulaText:="C"
```

instead of 100 lines that go:

```
SolverAdd cellRef:=range("A1)", relation:=1, formulaText:=Range("B1")
SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("A1"), relation:=3, formulaText:=Range("C1")
...
SolverAdd cellRef:=range("A25)", relation:=1, formulaText:=Range("B25")
SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("A25"), relation:=3, formulaText:=Range("C25")
```

...

and so on ?

Comment: You can use a loop - no need for 100 lines

Answer (score 0):

You can used named ranges, and in fact it is a good idea for readability. `"A","B","C"` are themselves not valid names, but things like `"A_"` are (though something which has a meaning in your model such as e.g. `"Purchase"` might be better). To use the named ranges, use syntax like this (which is similar to your proposed syntax):

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("A_"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="B_"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("A_"), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="C_"
```

which should work as expected.

Here is a complete example: `A_` is the name of `A1:A50`, `B_` of `B1:B50` and `C_` of `C1:C50`. I use `A51` as the objective function which is simply the sum of `A_`. I initialize `A_` to be all `0`, `B_` to be all `10` and `C_` to be all `1`. Then I run the following code:

```
Sub Test()
    SolverOk SetCell:="$A$51", MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:="A_", Engine:=2
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("A_"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="B_"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("A_"), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="C_"
    SolverSolve True
End Sub
```

After running the code, `A_` contains all `10`, as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I am afraid that did not work. Note that, as per your syntax, A_ , B_, and C_ are an entire range of cells, NOT a single cell.

Comment: @TolgaUzuner: I tried it on an entire range of cells and it does work. When using the solver, it is seldom necessary to enter constraints one cell at a time. I will edit the question to show a complete example.

Comment: @TolgaUzuner If the code doesn't work for you -- what error message are you getting?